# How to see if a file has CAP_NET_ADMIN?

Tags: linux, files, capabilities

I ran the following command:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_net_bind_service+eip `which nmap`
```

Now I'd like to add to my `~/.zshrc` a line that detects such settings and exports `NMAP_PRIVILEGED=1`. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `getcap`:

```
if nmap --version >/dev/null && getcap `which nmap` | grep -q cap_net_raw; then
  export NMAP_PRIVILEGED="1"
else
  echo "WARNING: No Nmap with cap_net_raw in \$PATH!" >&2
fi
```